# Autoloading PHP file in composer package

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to create a composer package that also contains src/functions.php with some general functions. I have the following in composer.json to make it autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["src/functions.php"]
}
```

When I import this package into a project it will try to load src/functions.php in the current project (local) in stead of the imported package. Is there a way to ensure the correct file is loaded when imported (./vendor/bla/src/functions.php)?

Comment: I'd recommend NOT using global, non-namespaced functions in a composer package--especially if it's for anyone else to use ever! At the very least make them static methods of a helper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoloading is not for loading everything. If `src/functions.php` contains class just ensure it's properly namespaced and I see no reason why autoloader would pick your local class instead of package's. If you are using the same namespace for the package and for code in your project then basically you should stop doing so.

If `src/functions.php` is just bunch of functions, then I strognly suggest refactoring the code and wrap them in properly namespaced class. You can make your functions [static methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) so basically not much would change from usage perspective.

**EDIT**

Once you finish refactoring, change your `composer.json` from what you shown in question to:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["src/"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, namespaces it is! :)